# Cannot assign attributes to form using Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.beginform

I have a form begun with the `Html.BeginForm()` helper method:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(
       null,null, new { @id = "MaintenanceForm", @class = "datatable", @nonvalidate="nonvalidate" }
    ))
```

and the form is rendered as:

```
<form action="(controller's name)/(current action's name)/MaintenanceForm?class=datatable" method="post">
```

The attributes such as id, class, and `nonvalidate` aren't assigned. Also I do not want a default Http Method. What can I do?

Comment: Your using the wrong overload - you need [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod,System.Object%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is matching with the below overload of BeginForm method

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues
)
```

The third parameter here is an object for the route values. These will be added as the querystring key value(s) to your form's `action` attribute value. That is the reason you are seeing those big url as the action attribute value.

If you want to specify the html attributes( *Id,class* etc), Use this overload which has a fourth parameter which takes the html attributes. The third parameter is the FormMethod.

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    FormMethod method,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

This should work.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Post",FormMethod.Post, 
       new { @id = "MaintenanceForm", @class = "datatable", @nonvalidate = "nonvalidate" }))
{

}
```

Replace `Create` and `Post` with your action method name and controller name.

Comment: Is there a way to not specify the FormMethod? I am doing post and get with `$.ajax()`

Comment: There are only 2 methods, GET or POST. What problem are you having when you explicitly set the FormMethod ? It should not give you any trouble with your ajax calls.